# unable to make a webview that contains html from string too look like most websites mobile versions (text goes out of the scree/ screen too small)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

I have a wordpress website with Json API installed.
Now I want to take the posts content and put it in a webview that has normal margins, breaklines that prevent the text to go out of the screen, prevent zoom in or zoom out (or these will just increase/ decrease font size), and consistent font size across all posts length.

Until now I used a textview, because I just couldn't make it look right, But textview can't show images or videos, and it looks worse overall than my website's mobile version.

this is an example of an html code content:

```
<p dir=\"ltr\"><strong>This is how a Post should look like</strong></p>\n<p dir=\"ltr\"> <span style=\"text-decoration: underline;\"><u>with underlines and highlights</u> </span></p>\n<p dir=\"ltr\">Paragraphs are the building blocks of papers. Many students define paragraphs in terms of length: a paragraph is a group of at least five sentences, a paragraph is half a page long, etc. In reality, though, the unity and coherence of ideas among sentences is what constitutes a paragraph. A paragraph is defined as “a group of sentences or a single sentence that forms a unit” (Lunsford and Connors 116). Length and appearance do not determine whether a section in a paper is a paragraph. For instance, in some styles of writing, particularly journalistic styles, a paragraph can be just one sentence long. Ultimately, a paragraph is a sentence or group of sentences that support one main idea. In this handout, we will refer to this as the “controlling idea,” because it controls what happens in the rest of the paragraph.</p>\n<p dir=\"ltr\">list of examples:</p>\n<ul>\n<li dir=\"ltr\" style=\"text-align: left;\">first itme</li>\n<li dir=\"ltr\" style=\"text-align: left;\">second item</li>\n</ul>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n
```

(you can ignore the "/n" I delete it through code)
this is how I want it too look like:

[image]

this is how it actually looks like:

[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G06lr.jpg)

[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59FtK.jpg)

as you can see there are no borders and it looks like a desktop site on smartphone.
thank you!

Comment: How does it look?

Comment: it looks like escaping borders...

Comment: Post a picture otherwise we can't help!

Comment: I added pictures Steven , Thanks!